# Why does scala cache ask me to define the TTL twice?

Tags: scala, caching

So I have been trying to get up to speed with scala cache. I was going through this documentation

https://cb372.github.io/scalacache/docs/

```
private val thisToThatCache =
   CaffeineCache(
     Caffeine.newBuilder
       .maximumSize(4096)
       .expireAfterWrite(4, TimeUnit.HOURS)
       .build[String, String)
```

and this caching call

```
 import scalacache.modes.try_._
 import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

 thisToThatCache.caching(thisStr)(ttl = 4.hours)(
    fetchThatForGivenThis(thisStr)
 )
```

Notice that I have defined the TTL twice, once using 4.hours in the caching call and the other based on 4 TimeUnit.Hours

This was a bit odd so I started investigating the CaffeineCache implementation

I looked at this

https://github.com/cb372/scalacache/blob/433d07ddb1249d7e6ec13fe7584a3d785be8d44d/modules/caffeine/src/main/scala/scalacache/caffeine/CaffeineCache.scala#L29

and I realized that irrespective of what I put the expire After Write value, the getter would think an artifact is expired if the caching ttl value is expired (at least it should).

And AFAIK the underlying cache defines eviction.

So my questions are

1. Whats the design decision for scala cache to have two different definitions for TTL. I.e. the concept of eviction and expiry are disconnected and defined separately ?

To explain what I mean a specific example of doPut https://github.com/cb372/scalacache/blob/433d07ddb1249d7e6ec13fe7584a3d785be8d44d/modules/caffeine/src/main/scala/scalacache/caffeine/CaffeineCache.scala#L42 here creates an Entry object and puts that in. The entry defines isExpired https://github.com/cb372/scalacache/blob/dd7f9988b3b1cab20ba2a9649a51a36210065607/modules/core/shared/src/main/scala/scalacache/Entry.scala#L13, which evaluates to false if the expiresAt is None. And finally the doGet : https://github.com/cb372/scalacache/blob/433d07ddb1249d7e6ec13fe7584a3d785be8d44d/modules/caffeine/src/main/scala/scalacache/caffeine/CaffeineCache.scala#L29 method checks if its expired (which it evaluates to false if the previous doPut for the key had expiredAt as None) and returns None since its deemed expired. Note at no point did it consult the expireAfter... timeout. So if I pass None, it should always evaluate to not found.

2. Whats the behavior if expireAfterWrite < ttl in caching. Is the expiry going to honor expireAfterWrite or is it dependent on the implementation (i.e. an underlying cache lazily evicting objects only when the cache has reached a bounded size)?

Answer (score 1):

Both the [code](https://github.com/cb372/scalacache/blob/83991f6d4fed1aab329e470a839b3e42ad45126f/modules/core/shared/src/main/scala/scalacache/AbstractCache.scala#L40) and the [docs](https://cb372.github.io/scalacache/docs/cache-implementations.html#cache2k) provide an explanation:

```
caching("benjamin")(ttl = None)
```

`ttl` is an `Option[Duration]`, so it should the value defined in

```
expireAfterWrite(4, TimeUnit.HOURS)
```

meanwhile, when you use:

```
caching("benjamin")(ttl = 4.hours) // implicit conversion to Some(4.hours)
```

you can override the default for a particular value. The implementation details depend on, well, implementation:

```
// abstract def that need to be implemented by particular cache implemetation
protected def doPut[F[_]](key: String, value: V, ttl: Option[Duration])(implicit mode: Mode[F]): F[Any]
```

As you can see it received optional ttl, and it can do whatever it wants with it (even ignore). The default value must be provided elsewhere and we can see in the docs, that's what builder do using `expireAfterWrite`.

Long story short, you DON'T have to provide ttl twice. Just pass `None` if you don't want to override the value.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a section after question 1 which shows an implementation which seemingly ignores the expireAfterWrite Value.

Comment: Well, the answer already contains answers to your update: interface implies that in builder you define the default, in put you define optional override; implementation defines how it will treat the 2 values, it should use ttl argument to completely override ttl, but you can write your own implementation which e.g. picks the minimum of the two.